# How android manages update for Pre-installed applications

Tags: android

In android Pre-Installed applications are stored in /system/app/ directory. And once we download update of that application the application is updated with latest version. My Question is:
1. When application gets updated, do pre-installed apk is removed and replaced with new version (I guess not) or updates are kept at some different directory, if so then where and also how system decides which one to launch?

Comment: "When application gets updated, do pre-installed apk is removed and replaced with new version" -- no. You can tell this by looking at any updated system app in Settings -- you can "Uninstall updates" and revert to the original app.

Comment: Actually that is my question, where does the new version of app gets installed /data/data/app ,/system/app or somewhere else, if this is different than /system/app then what location and if this same location then how 2 different versions are maintained (as on uninstalling updates previous version stays)